# The different ways to distinguish between left and right mouse click, which one to use?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm feeling a little confused. I'm working on a HTML5 game project and for a specific menu I want the user to be able to add value to an image through a function using left click but then remove value with right click instead of the menu showing up. I have read about 3 ways to do this:

I've been assigning the event listener to a div, for some reason I can't get `if (event.button === 2)` to work, even though I read that was the right mouse button. However the `div.oncontextmenu = doRightClick;` works just fine. And then there's `event.which`, which I still don't seem to understand. It seems like a  global event.button but with keyboard keys included?

My question is, is there a reason to ever use `event.button` or `event.which` over `.oncontextmenu`? Is there any advantages to one over the other? Or browser issues with any? I read that `event.button` has different values for IE8 and under which is kinda lame. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The `click` event (usually) applies only to the left mouse button and (sometimes) the middle button. But the `mousedown` event applies to all buttons.

Comment: Ah you are right, mousedown makes the event.button === 2 work now. But adding return false; at the end of the function won't stop the default right click menu from popping up? Thanks for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contextmenu` event isn't really for right-clicks; it's for context menus, however they're invoked (context menu keyboard key, special click with one-button mice, etc.). You'll probably want to still capture those `contextmenu` events so you can cancel them, but then use `mousedown` or `mouseup` for specifically handling right-clicks.

Comment: Ah dang, did not know there was a context menu keyboard key! This is starting to make sense now, so you are saying keep the .oncontextmenu = function() { return false; } and then have the mousedown listener deal with the right click through event.button === 2 ? Thanks for all your help btw

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Sorry to ask another question but, would you say it's ok to add the .oncontextmenu = function () { return false; } to the body? Just so the page feels more like an app/game with no context menu at all? Or should I try to avoid that and only add it to the stuff my users will be using right click on?

Comment: Adding to the body seems reasonable for a game.